# what's this /*global $, window: false, document: false */

Tags: javascript

Why do some javascript developers put this type of hidden code on top of their pages?

```
 /*global $, window: false, document: false */
```

Comment: Look into jshint and jslint.

Comment: http://www.jslint.com/lint.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> JSLint also recognizes a /*global*/ directive that can indicate to JSLint that variables used in this file were defined in other files. The directive can contain a comma separated list of names. Each name can optionally be followed by a colon and either true or false, true indicating that the variable may be assigned to by this file, and false indicating that assignment is not allowed (which is the default). The directive respects function scope. Source: http://www.jslint.com/lint.html

Based on your example, the developer is telling to JSLint that `$` is defined in other file, `window` and `document` are defined by browser and the assignment is not allowed.

Answer (score 2):

It's used for JSLint, a way to optimize Javascript.

http://www.jslint.com/